# CodeIgniter Active Record result object creating Infinite Loop

Tags: php, loops, activerecord, codeigniter-2, infinite

doing a simple Active Record select.  It looks a little something like this:

```
 $query = $CI->db->select( 'answer' )
                  ->where( 'qID', $xid )
                  ->get( 'qAnswer' );
```

$query becomes the expected CI_DB_mysql_result Object with result rows and a current row of 0.  Expected.

```
while($row = $query->row() )
 {
   print_r( $row );
   // some actual code
  }
```

This is a commonly used pattern - but this time it triggers an infinite loop.  When I output the row, it turns out that $query is dumping the first initial row infinitely many times.  It is never iterating.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2298 seems related but does not lead to a solution.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter function row() returns a single row. So you code become infinite.
Try this construction:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    print_r($row);
}
```

OR

```
while($row = $query->next_row() ){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had ended up going with the foreach construct.  My understanding was that row() functioned as next_row().  Whoops!